# Uninstall a package that I have installed using a .sh script

Tags: bash, package-management, uninstall

I have more older versions of NetBeans installed on my system and I would like to uninstall them.

The problem is that I have installed them all from a `.sh` shell installer script simply running from cmd and none of Synaptics, apt, dpkg nor Software center knows about any NetBeans installation.

I know I could probably run the installer again and select the `Uninstall/Remove` option but I have already deleted all of the installers long time ago and downloading them again just to be able to uninstall current installations is not a solution for me.

Is it possible to just delete the local files (since none of the packaging software knows about them) and consider this operation as *uninstall*? Or is there some better option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also have NetBeans 7.3 installed on my Ubuntu 14.04. It was installed using `*.sh` into `/usr/local/netbeans-7.3`. And I have `/usr/local/netbeans-7.3/uninstall.sh` there. You can try to find it using this:

```
$ locate -ir netbeans.*uninstall.*sh$
```

Answer (score 2):

I had long time ago also installed Netbeans using the scripts and package provided on their web site.

In my case, the software was installed below `/opt/netbeans-<version>`, so I had just to remove this directory and the program was gone as he had no need of startup scripts or whatsoever.

If you want to keep the projects you're made with previous version, don't touch to the `$HOME/.netbeans` directory, it can be re-used by any new version, even if installed using the Ubuntu package manager.

Answer (score 0):

The script which was supposed to do the uninstall is doing a reproducible series of steps in an automated fashion. If you reproduce that series of steps *identically*, but manually, you will get to the same state. The problem here is figuring out *which* steps were executed, which depends entirely on the uninstall program. You could conceivably read the source code and replicate its actions manually, but I can only recommend that if you are a programmer *and* the source code is very simple, which is unlikely for a complex software package.

Comment: I would do -1 here but my rep does not allow me yet. This is completely uncomfortable solution. Downloading an installer again would be much more comfortable than your solution...

Comment: Well, you were the one who said you wanted to uninstall completely without downloading the installer.

Comment: Yes, but check other answers here and the original question which mine is possible duplicate of - there is so easy solution...

Comment: I didn't realise the NetBeans installer didn't remove itself when uninstalling. You could consider this a completely generic way of removing any program without an uninstaller.

Comment: The problem was I did not know about NetBeans having an uninstaller... Knowing that I wouldn't have asked here...